# Regex that matches words separated by a semicolon and whitespace

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to write a regular expression that matches either multiple words separated by a semicolon and optionally whitespace, or a single word on its own without any adjoining semicolons.

For example, I want to match `bla` and `bla ; bla`, but I don't want to match: `bla . bla` or `bla;`, i.e., the semicolon should only be captured if it appears between two words, not at the end of the string.

Comment: Can you give us some more examples of what will match and not match as well as what you have tried?

Comment: What language are you using? It matters because you may or may not have negative lookaheads.

Comment: Just use `;(?!$)` if you need to match a `;` not at the end of the string/line.

Answer (score 5):

Try this `\w\s*?([;])(?=\s*?\w)` which will match all ";" which are preceded and followed by white space and a word character

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that he wants to *exclude* other punctuation (`"bla . bla" or "bla;" wont match`) but wants to include the surrounding words and white space. This is a step in the right direction but not quite there.

Comment: I thought about something like ;(?!$) witch will match any ; that isnt follow by the end of the string. but will happen if there is no ; at all? will it match?

Comment: Well,,if the ';' where at the end of a string like 'hi there; ' the regex requires that the ';' be followed by zero or more whitespace and a word character, so the end of a string will not match. You can try it out here http://www.rubular.com/r/IBd8jNIhJj

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
[a-z]+(?:;[a-z]+)?
```

if you want more than one or two words, just replace ? by *

(Notice : this pattern don't deal with spaces and cases or some other things. You must add them if you need)